# Validate checkbox with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Again i'm having trouble with checkboxes. I'm getting info from an API and showing like checkbox. The problem comes when i'm triying to add a validation. This is a part of my code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var fact = {
        templateUrl: './app/components/fact.components.html',
        controller: factCtrl
    };
    angular.module('fApp').component('odcFacturas', fact);
    factCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "couponApi"];

    function factCtrl($scope, couponApi) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.clientOrder = null;
            vm.all = false;
            vm.sendData = function() {
                vm.apiData = couponApi.get({
                    idOrder: vm.idOrder
                }).$promise.then(function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Response.length; i++) {
                        data.Response[i].Select = vm.all;
                    }
                    vm.coupons = data.Response;
                    vm.combo = data.Response.length > 0;
                });
            }
```

Here i call the info, and the next part of my code check all the checkboxes:

```
vm.selectAll = function() {
 for (var i = 0; i < vm.coupons.length; i++) {
     vm.coupons[i].Select = vm.all;
 }
 if (vm.all == 0) {
     alert("Select at least one coupon");
 }
}
```

How can I trigger three validations with a submit button? I mean: what I want to do is validate three cases:

1. if the checkbox "select all checkboxes" is checked, submit
2. if there's no selected checkboxes, show the alert message
3. if there's at least one checkbox (or 'n' checkboxes) selected,
   submit

On the HTML view i have this:

```
<div class ="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="cbx input-group">
            <div class="checkbox" name="imtesting" ng-show="$ctrl.coupons.length > 0">
                    <label><input type="checkbox"
                           ng-show="$ctrl.coupons.length > 0"
                           name="allCoupons"
                           ng-model="$ctrl.all"
                           ng-click="$ctrl.selectAll()"/>Select all coupons</label>



                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="c in $ctrl.coupons">
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               name="couponBox"
                               ng-model="c.Select"
                               ng-click="$ctrl.result()"
                               required/>{{c.CodeCoupon}}
                            <br>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <label class="label label-danger" ng-show="submitted == true && !ctrl.newTest()">Select at least one coupon</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Select` property from each coupon object like

```
vm.canSubmit = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i< vm.coupons.length; i++)
    {
        if (vm.coupons[i].Select) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redo the way you are handling your `selectsAll` function. When you are using angular there is a thing called `scope.$apply` that is actually running which tells the dom to update if the object or properties have changed. Sometimes if you use for loops the way you are using them it wont register a change.

Try this and it should work:

```
vm.selectAll = function()
    {
         vm.all = !vm.all;
         vm.coupons.forEach(function(o){
            o.Select = vm.all;
         })

    }

 vm.submit = function(){
     var checked = 0;
     vm.coupons.forEach(function(o){
        if(o.Select === true)
           checked +=1;
     })
     if(vm.all || checked > 0){
         //submit here
     }
     else if(checked === 0){
         //error
     }
 }
```

This will work both ways. If checked it will check all and if unchecked it will uncheck all. That validation will work for all three scenarios.